# Interpreting float data in C

Tags: c++, c, casting, floating-point, int

I am debugging a issue where the data coming out in a buffer gets a wrong value. I am sending the buffer (`u8`) type from Kernel driver to HAL. In HAL there is a `Uint16` buffer which is receiving the values from this buffer.

```
//Code to copy BUFFLEN contents from u8 data[BUFFLEN] into uint16_tData ;

uint16_t uint16_tData[BUFFLEN / 2];
float floatdata[BUFFLEN / 2];
```

I am getting the float values from the `uint16_tData` buffer using this type cast:

```
floatdata[index] = (*((float *)((void *)&uint16_tData[index1];
```

Now my question: How Can I interpret the data residing in the `floatdata` array?
Say I have data `floatdata[0] = 53640;`

How can I Interpret a float data out of this nibble in `floatdata[0]`

Note 4 bytes from u8 --> 2 elements of array uint16_tData --> one element of array floatdata.

I wanted to know with an example that say:

Values transmitted from the driver are:

```
u8 val1 = 206
u8 val2 = 208
u8 val3 = 120
u8 val4 = 68
```

In the HAL, how will the conversion take place and what values will I get here?

```
uint16_tData[0] = ?
uint16_tData[1] = ?
```

And how will it be the interpretation of the data as a float in `floatdata`?

```
floatdata[0] = ?
```

Comment: It is likely to be [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) single precision, which is quite easy to decode. See the link to Wikipedia.

Comment: Note that you are reading two 16bit ints as a float and so endianness could break things here. This apart, the Q is not clear to me: did you really want to know about IEEE754? What's the point in showing us where it comes from then? Can you clarify your doubt?

Comment: edited the Qs , I dont know IEEE754.It could be this standard I may be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Why do this at all?

I think you want this:

```
float *floatdata;

floatdata = (float *)uint16_tData;

// Now use floatdata[index] ...
```

Casting items one at a time is silly.  Casting from uint16_t to float is even sillier, it would be better keep it as uint8_t (bytes) whic his what it seems to come in as, or at least use uint32_t as the intermediate.

Is there anything that prevents you from doing this?  Can you think of how you can redesign your code so you can avoid dealing with these issues entirely?

Comment: I cant change the design right now.Moreover the items present under the uint16_tData are of different types(not the data type but of say different nature , Key presses, sensor data)

Answer (score 1):

according to my understanding of your question is this what you want

```
float f ;
uint8_t u8arr[4]={206,208,120,68};
uint16_t arr[2];
memcpy(&arr[0],u8arr,2);
memcpy(&arr[1],u8arr+2,2);
memcpy(&f,arr,4);
```

Answer (score 1):

`uint16` are "made of" 2 `u8`, and single precision `float` is 32 bit (4 u8 or 2 uint16), but how they are "converted" it depends on the code that handles those data, in particular in the *meaning* of "sending" (from kernel driver) and how the code that "receives" expect the data. I admit I am ignorant about the topic and I can't check and research it now, but I suspect you have a problem of **endianness**: your data have a "meaning" altogether, not as single octets, but you put them in memory in the wrong order.

Basically, you have a buffer which contains your octects, say

```
A   B   C   D
u8  u8  u8  u8      4 u8 arr element (arr[0], arr[1] ...)
\____/  \____/  
 uint16   uint16    2 uint16 arr element (arr[0] and arr[1])
```

in this order of increasing memory address. If you want that `A B` is read as the "correct" uint16 number, you have to "sort" it in memory so that you match the endianness of the processor: e.g. if you want the number `A*8 + B` on a little endian cpu, you have to write two u8 in memory in the opposite order:

```
B A D C
```

I suspect HAL uses uint16 just to store data, not to interpret them as 16bit number, so the endianness here is not a problem. But it is once you want to get the correct "float" from 4 u8 (or 2 uint16) in memory: you have to put the u8 in the correct order.

If you want that your u8s are interpreted as float through a cast, you first have to put them in the opposite order in a little endian machine, e.g.

```
  address of arr8[0] and arr16[0]
/
D   C   B   A
u8  u8  u8  u8      4 u8 arr element (arr8[0], arr8[1] ...)
\____/  \____/  
 uint16   uint16    2 uint16 arr element (arr16[0] and arr16[1])
```

Then, if you "read" those octets as float on a litte endian machine you have the right "float".

So, it is up to you to sort correctly your u8, knowing that they will be interpreted as another type with a "width" wider than one octet. Portable code should use proper ways to compile correctly for processors with different endianness.

See also [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating-point_and_endianness)

Answer (score 0):

I am not HAL/DX friendly so it can be a silly note
but are you sure that your floats are 16bit and not 32bit?

- if not then you need 2x16bit uint per single 32bit float and the bug is there.
- If yes then read further

  1. go here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc308050(v=vs.85).aspx#alpha_16_bit
  2. look for 16 bit rules
  3. look for the bit count and locations (sign,exp,mantisa)

ok now what is your problem:

1. you have uint buffers but store float inside ?

   - in this case just do this:

     ```
     float16 *p=(float16*)uint16_tData;
     ```
   - and use p instead of uint16_tData
2. you have uint buffers with uint values stored inside ?

   - this means you need to convert uint to float
   - use internal = operator if exists
   - if not write your own conversion
   - you can ignore sign for uints
   - set exp to 0 (2^0)
   - set mantissa to uint value
   - truncate unfitted bits
   - just shift right / inc exponent until MSB of uint fits into mantissa
   - put all together with bit shift/and/or  to their places (see that link above)
3. you have float values and need to store them in uint as uint

   - so simply do backwards previous point
   - extract exponent, mantisa, ignore sign or use 2'os complement
   - shift mantisa left by exponent (if positive)  else right by -exponent
   - and that is it.

PS. be aware on some platforms/compilers/data types the bit shift can insert also ones from carry or the other side of number. In that case and the result with bit-mask.

PPS. do not forget to apply exponent bias !!!

Hope it helps a little